# How to randomize shapes and colors using turtle python?

Tags: python, python-turtle

Can someone please help me with drawing random shapes in random colors using turtle python?

Comment: Please share your attempt first.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing your attempt first is appreciated. Here is a simple program that chooses a random colour and shape from a list and draws it. You can add more colours in the list or more functions to draw different shapes.

Feel free to ask for clarifications in the comments below...

```
import random

color_list = ["red" , "green" , "blue"]
shape_list = ["square" , "circle" , "triangle"]

myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
myTurtle.hideturtle()
myTurtle.color(random.choice(color_list))

def drawSquare():
    for i in range(4):
        myTurtle.forward(100)
        myTurtle.left(90)

def drawCircle():
    myTurtle.circle(100)

def drawTriangle():
    for i in range(3):
        myTurtle.forward(100)
        myTurtle.left(120)
        
random_shape = random.choice(shape_list)

if random_shape == "square":
    drawSquare()
elif random_shape == "circle":
    drawCircle()
elif random_shape == "triangle":
    drawTriangle()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some very straight-forward code for random moves and colors:

```
import turtle
import random
pat = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.Screen().bgcolor('black')
colors = ["red", "yellow", "blue"]

for i in range(500):
    pat.color(random.choice(colors))
    x = random.randint(1,4)
    if x == 1:
        pat.forward(30)
    elif x == 2:
        pat.back(30)
    elif x == 3:
        pat.right(30)
    elif x == 4:
        pat.left(30)
```